# Dynamic Audio Player

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

I have this php file. I can not get it to play the songs that appear as links, in the audio player above the links when you click them. (See the bottom of my post to see what the page looks like)

I am also unable to omit the files in that display that are not .mp3 files.

Can somebody tell me how this is done please ? I am new to PHP so help would be apprectaited.

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" >
<source src="http://miksdev.co.uk/Audio/Professor%20Green%20-%20The%20Green%20Lectures%20Vol%201%282%29/08StayHigh.mp3">
//Your Fallback goes here
</audio>



<ul id="playlist">
<?php

//path to directory to scan
$directory = dirname(__FILE__)."/";

//get all files in specified directory
$files = glob($directory . "*");

//print each file name
foreach($files as $file)
{
 //check to see if the file is a folder/directory
 if(is_file($file))
 {

 if(basename($file)!="list.php"){
  ?>
 <li class="active">  
<a href="<?php echo basename($file); ?>"><?php echo basename($file); ?></a><br>
 </li>   
  <?php }}}?>
</ul>
```

The above file displays the files at the following location as links

[Professor Green The Green Lectures Vol 2](http://miksdev.co.uk/Audio/Professor%20Green%20-%20The%20Green%20Lectures%20Vol%201%282%29/)

[You can see how the page looks at this link](http://miksdev.co.uk/Audio/Professor%20Green%20-%20The%20Green%20Lectures%20Vol%201%282%29/Newestdynamicplaylist.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `if` statement in your PHP file to discard non-MP3 files. For example with :

```
if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'php') {...}
```

The problem with your javascript code is you call your `init()` function too early. Wait that your page is loaded and call it.

You should add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    init();
</script>
```

at the bottom of your page (before `</body>`) and remove the one in your `audio with playlist.js` file.